# LeetCode 417 solution in C++. I'm getting a heap buffer overflow error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working through this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/pacific-atlantic-water-flow/
After battling through my own solution for several hours, I ended up not being able to fully solve it, so I'm tracing through how others did it. My new code is based on this: https://leetcode.com/problems/pacific-atlantic-water-flow/discuss/608490/C%2B%2B-Implementation-(DFS)

It's basically the same, except I made it more verbose, and I added some comments for clarity. Even though the code is virtually the same, I'm getting a heap overflow error for very large inputs. I'm not sure what's causing it, but I'm guessing that I'm not correctly passing references to vectors and end up making copies in memory. Can someone please help me figure out the inefficiency?

```
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

bool isOutOfBounds(int row, int col, vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    bool rowOutOfBound = row < 0 || row == matrix.size();
    bool colOutOfBound = col < 0 || col == matrix[0].size();

    return rowOutOfBound || colOutOfBound;
}

void explore(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int i, int j, int prevHeight, vector<vector<bool>>& explored) {
    // if we are out of bounds, or our height is greater, or if this cell was already explored
    if (isOutOfBounds(i, j, matrix) || matrix[i][j] < prevHeight || explored[i][j]) return;

    int height = matrix[i][j];
    explored[i][j] = true;

    explore(matrix, i - 1, j, height, explored); // flow up
    explore(matrix, i, j + 1, height, explored); // flow right
    explore(matrix, i + 1, j, height, explored); // flow down
    explore(matrix, i, j - 1, height, explored); // flow left
}

vector<vector<int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {

    vector<vector<int>> result;
    if (matrix.size() == 0) return result;

    // create boolean grids of explored paths, one for pacific, one for atlantic
    vector<vector<bool>> pacific(matrix.size(), vector<bool>(matrix[0].size(), false));
    vector<vector<bool>> atlantic(pacific);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        explore(matrix, i, 0, INT_MIN, pacific);                    // explore first column
        explore(matrix, i, matrix.size() - 1, INT_MIN, atlantic);   // explore last column
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++) {
        explore(matrix, 0, j, INT_MIN, pacific);                     // explore first row
        explore(matrix, matrix[j].size() - 1, j, INT_MIN, atlantic); // explore last row
    }

    // for every column of each row
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++) {
            if (pacific[i][j] && atlantic[i][j]) {
                result.push_back({ i, j });
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


void main() {
    vector<vector<int>> matrix {
        { 1, 2, 2, 3, 5 },
        { 3, 2, 3, 4, 4 },
        { 2, 4, 5, 3, 1 },
        { 6, 7, 1, 4, 5 },
        { 5, 1, 1, 2, 4 }
    };
    vector<vector<int>> expected{ {0, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0} };

    vector<vector<int>> result = pacificAtlantic(matrix);
    assert(result == expected);
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the code will never move by more than 1 cell at a time, so there will never be a case when row > matrix.size().

Comment: For "large inputs" perhaps the reallocations needed for `result.push_back({ i, j })` could simply fail at one point. Perhaps you should try to calculate the size needed, and [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the memory needed beforehand?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "large inputs"? How "large" are we talking about? What will be the sizes of the vectors you create?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yikes, I found the problem. It wasn't large inputs, it was rectangular grids. I mixed up "explore last column" and "explore last row" so I was trying to access invalid vector indexes.

Comment: Shouldn't `row == matrix.size()` etc be `row >= matrix.size()`? Maybe "it should never occur", but as an experienced developer I've heard that many times...  better to be safe than sorry. There's no extra cost.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error when exploring last column, and last row, so was accessing invalid vector indexes.
when I fixed

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        explore(matrix, i, 0, INT_MIN, pacific);                    // explore first column
        explore(matrix, i, matrix.size() - 1, INT_MIN, atlantic);   // explore last column
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++) {
        explore(matrix, 0, j, INT_MIN, pacific);                     // explore first row
        explore(matrix, matrix[j].size() - 1, j, INT_MIN, atlantic); // explore last row
    }
```

the solution worked.

The code should have read as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
    explore(matrix, i, 0, INT_MIN, pacific);                       // explore first column
    explore(matrix, i, matrix[0].size() - 1, INT_MIN, atlantic);   // explore last column
}

for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++) {
    explore(matrix, 0, j, INT_MIN, pacific);                     // explore first row
    explore(matrix, matrix.size() - 1, j, INT_MIN, atlantic);    // explore last row
}
```